# How to remove lines from the sides in opencv?

Tags: opencv

I have to remove some lines from the sides of hundreds of grayscale images.

[image]

In this image lines appear in three sides.

The lines are not consistent though, i.e, they appear above, below, left and/or right side of the image. And they are of unequal length and width.

Comment: is there other things rather than the line that you do not want to lose at the borders of the image?

Comment: That thing in the middle is handwritten scanned text. It should remain intact. As it is handwritten they do not always appear at the exact middle.

Comment: So, is it possible that this handwritten be in the most left of the image?

Comment: Possible, but it is rare.

Answer (score 1):

If you could assume that the borders are free of important information, you may crop the photo like this:

C++ code:

```
cv::Mat img;
//load your image into img;
int padding=MAX_WIDTH_HEIGHT_OF_THE LINEAS_AREA
img=img(cv::Rect(padding,padding,img.cols-padding,img.rows-padding));
```

---

If not, you have to find a less dumb solution like this for example:

1. Findcontours
2. Delete contours that are far from the borders.
3. Draw contours on blank image
4. Apply hough line with suitable thresholds.
5. Delete contours that intersect with lines inside the image border.

---

Another solution, assuming the handwritten shape is connected:

1. Findcontours
2. Get the contour with the biggest area.
3. Draw it on a blank image with -1(fill) flag in the strock argument.
4. bitwise_and between the original image and the one you made

---

Another solution, asuming that the handwritten shape could be discontinuity :

1. Findcontours
2. Delete any contour that its **all** points are very close to the border (using euclidian distance with a threshold)
3. Draw all remaining contours on a blank image with -1(fill) flag in the strock argument.
4. bitwise_and between the original image and the one you made

P.S. I did not touch HoughLine transform since I do not about the shapes. I assume that some of them may contain very straight lines.

Comment: If you have problem implementing them I can help if you are using C++

Comment: Yes I am using c++. I am trying to implement the second solution.

Comment: Finding the contour with biggest area does not work because sometimes the shape in the middle have disjoint parts